# SELECT DISTINCT one column but return all

Tags: sql

I have a query like this:

```
$sql_place = "SELECT * FROM place
INNER JOIN join_appointment_place 
ON join_appointment_place.id_place = place.id_place
INNER JOIN join_event_appointment 
ON join_appointment_place.id_appointment = join_event_appointment.id_appointment
WHERE join_event_appointment.id_event = " . $EVENT_ID . "
ORDER BY place.title, place.category";
```

The problem is that I need to return all the places with different `titles`. So I should use a `DISTINCT`. But how do I select the `DISTINCT` `title` and at the same time return all the other values?

```
  $sql_place = "SELECT 
  DISTINCT 
  place.id_place, 
  place.avatar, 
  place.category, 
  place.title, 
  place.description, 
  place.address, 
  place.latitude,
  place.longitude, 
  place.email, 
  place.web, 
  place.shared FROM place
  INNER JOIN join_appointment_place 
  ON join_appointment_place.id_place = place.id_place
  INNER JOIN join_event_appointment 
  ON join_appointment_place.id_appointment = join_event_appointment.id_appointment
  WHERE join_event_appointment.id_event = " . $EVENT_ID . "
  ORDER BY place.title, place.category";
```

The above is what I tried. But I am worried that is applying the DISTINCT not only to the `title`, but to each selected column and this is not what I am looking for.
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: show some sample data with expected results. You'll likely have to do some grouping, selecting min/max of other columns if there is non-repeating data

Comment: In table `place` there are places with same title? why first query not work...

Comment: It would really help us if you would show some sample data and desired result.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: The problem is you want DISTINCT titles, but which one of the values do you want on the other columns. for example avatar column might have different values for same title, how do we know which one of them do you want to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use GROUP BY place.title if you just want to get those title.

Comment: I don't need to get only the titles,
I need to select all the places but only those with different titles..this is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will return a distinct on every column but that's no bad thing. For example a distinct query like that could return:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
1       ABC     XYZ     Y
1       ABC     XYZ     N
```

While your question makes it sound like you are expecting it to only retrieve distinct values for each and every column.

Comment: I need to select all the places but only those with different titles..this is what I am looking for

Comment: **`AND place.title in (select place.title from place group by place.title having count(1)=1)`** Place this in **`where`** clause

Answer (score 0):

The right query is by using `GROUP BY`
Thanks anyway.

```
$sql_place = "SELECT * FROM place
                  INNER JOIN join_appointment_place ON join_appointment_place.id_place = place.id_place
                  INNER JOIN join_event_appointment ON join_appointment_place.id_appointment = join_event_appointment.id_appointment
                  WHERE join_event_appointment.id_event = " . $EVENT_ID . "
                  GROUP BY place.title ORDER BY place.title, place.category";
```

Comment: Consider accepting Drixson's answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you are concerned you can use a nested query.

Select distinct titles and uses the results in the where clause of the outer query.

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE title IN (SELECT DISTINCT title FROM titles WHERE title > 'X');
```

Comment: could you provide an example?